# How to use 'would have been' properly (in this case)

Tags: grammaticality

recently I faced up this kinda sentence and I wonder which one is grammatically correct? (I'm not a native English speaker)

> I never thought someone would have written this article.

or

> I never would have thought someone would have written this article.

or, if none of them are proper sentences, can you write the correct one similar to these?

Comment: I think both are grammatically correct. Most people would probably say the first one.

Comment: Or *I never would have thought that someone would write that article.*

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I have one more question, is there any particular difference between those two sentences, I've written above and this third one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're both grammatical, and in principle have different meanings (though in practice there's probably little difference).

> I never thought that ...

The simple past makes a categorical statement: I have never had that thought (or held that belief).

> I never would have thought that ...

"Would have" is making the stronger claim that not only did I not think it, but I could not possibly have thought it.